# How do you separate interface from implementation with data members that are not static?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, static

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
public:
    static int staticNumber;
    static std::string staticText;
    int regularNumber;
    std::string regularText;
};

// I know how do it for static types
int Person::staticNumber = 0;

std::string Person::staticText = "Default";

// How would I do it for regular types?

int Person::regularNumber = 0; // I get an error here

std::string Person::regularText = "@"; // I get an error here

int main() {
    Person::staticNumber += 10;
    std::cout << Person::staticNumber << "\n";
    Person::staticText += "!";
    std::cout << Person::staticText << "\n";
}
```

As you can see from the code snippet it works fine with static data members. But as soon as I do it with ones without the word static I get an error. How do you separate interface from implementation with data members that are not static?

Comment: You don't need to mention the non-static member variables outside of the class the way you do for static member variables.

Comment: Do you understand why lines such as `std::string Person::staticText = "Default";` are necessary in the first place and what `static` means? Do you know how class instances and constructors work? If you do, then I think the question should answer itself, otherwise I would suggest reading up on that in a textbook again or clarifying your question (i.e. why you think something like `int Person::regularNumber = 0;` should be necessary), since I could also be misunderstanding it.

Comment: *"I know how do it for static types"* -- and what is "it"? Your question is supposed to be of use to future visitors with the same question. Are these people supposed to search for "it" to find your question? Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A non-static data member is associated with a specific instance of that object. To modify it, you create an object, then modify that object's data.

```cpp
Person p;

p.regularNumber = 1234;
```

That said, public access to data members tends to be frowned upon. The point of object orientation is largely to support higher-level operations, not just collect related data together.